# Is it possible to run a INSERT IGNORE INTO statement with multiple values?

Tags: mysql

It looks like the MySQL `INSERT IGNORE INTO` statement below is rejected by the MySQL server on the basis of a referential integrity constraint bouncing off one of the values, in one of the lines, whereas the other line is perfectly fine.

Example:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (field1, field2) VALUES
('val11', 'val12'),
('val21', 'val22');
```

With a referential integrity constraint binding field2 to table2.

Let *val12* be found in *table2*.
Let *val22* **NOT** be found in *table2*.

When such a statement is run, no line is inserted at all, whereas really, I was expecting the first line to be accepted, even though the second one was to be rejected, because of the reference not being met.

A workaround for me was to split the statement in two `INSERT IGNORE INTO`,
but I don't want that for performance reasons.

Is there any way to make that statement *do its best*, as opposed to a complete rejection on error?

Comment: You want to avoid duplicate entry right ? Have you used INSERT INTO ..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: Nope, I've got no duplicates issue, only referential integrity issues: I want what's possible to be inserted to be inserted, and not the whole insert to be cancelled because of one reference missing.